# Parse JSON error with Java And AWS Lambda function

Tags: java, json, amazon-web-services, lambda

I suspect this may be hiding another problem but unsure what it is - I've a small Lambda function that I'm trying to test using the AWS console.

```
    public class ApplicationRunner implements RequestHandler<String, String> {

    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ApplicationRunner.class);

    @Override
    public String handleRequest(String input, Context context) {
    //code

}
}
```

The error I am receiving is:

```
    {
  "errorMessage": "An error occurred during JSON parsing",
  "errorType": "java.lang.RuntimeException",
  "stackTrace": [],
  "cause": {
    "errorMessage": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@6cc4c815; line: 1, column: 1]",
    "errorType": "java.io.UncheckedIOException",
    "stackTrace": [],
    "cause": {
      "errorMessage": "Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: lambdainternal.util.NativeMemoryAsInputStream@6cc4c815; line: 1, column: 1]",
      "errorType": "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException",
      "stackTrace": [
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:148)",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.mappingException(DeserializationContext.java:857)",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:62)",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StringDeserializer.deserialize(StringDeserializer.java:11)",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bindAndClose(ObjectReader.java:1511)",
        "com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:1102)"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Comment: Your code is a little bit hazy in my crystal ball. I can't quite read it properly. Do you mind posting it here instead?

Comment: @Michael, consider your wish granted.

Comment: Can you post the input to this Lambda (the event data)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have:

- `rawData`: data that is sent to your lambda function
- `rewrittenData`: data after applying a transformation template
- `jsonData`: result of json-parsing of `rewriteData`

The signature `handleRequest(String input, Context context)` means that your `input` is `jsonData`, and this JSON object is a string. Do you pass a json-string into your lambda? 99.99% that not, that you are sending an object, so you get the error message as expected.

What you want is to extend the class `RequestStreamHandler` and override the function with the signature:

```
@Override
public void handleRequest(final InputStream input, final OutputStream output, final Context context)
```

Now `input` is your `rewrittenData`, which is most likely the same as `rawData`.